# FaceTime Recorder

Tags: iphone, facetime

How do I get access to the video calls made in facetime, I want to record them as we talk. Anyone tried this?

David H

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible to do, as you cannot capture the video input and output while the Phone app is using them.